# Como esticar um elemento até o final da tela?

Tags: html, css

Como esticar um elemento até o final da página levando em consideração a posição que ele se encontra?

ex:

```
 <div class="caixa1">CAIXA 1</div>
 <div class="caixa2">CAIXA 2</div>

.caixa1{background-color: red;}
.caixa2{background-color: blue;}
```

Como fazer para que a caixa2 se estique até o final da tela?

Note que não estou procurando um exemplo de rodapé!

Preferencialmente sem uso de javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Viva,

Podes ver o exemplo aqui: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVNZqr

Apenas tens de usar:

```
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
```

Abraço e boa sorte ;)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas o seu exemplo avança além do limite da tela.

Comment: Adaptei o seu exemplo, e parece que funcionou, bastou um pequeno ajuste adicionando `overflow:hidden` e `height:100%` na body

Comment: Sim, por normal isso já deve ser feito quando se começa um novo projeto, mas sim tem razão :)

Answer (score 1):

Em qualquer uma das soluções você está tendo overflow da div na página, o ideal é você calcular a altura dela, desta forma:

```
height: calc (100% - a);
```

Onde `a` é a distância do objeto ao topo da página, creio que só com js podemos pegar essa valor dinamicamente, desta forma é melhor inserir manualmente.

Comment: Se não me engano o calc () é um recurso do css 3